# Gcov to consider filename and function name as an input for computing code coverage

Tags: gcov

Currently in our project both our client and our team working parallelly, to build the code both teams modules code required. We are using gcov for code coverage. Currently the generated coverage shows both teams. Is there any way to generate the unit gcov coverage only for our module.(Our module doesn’t build alone).

Is there any way is available to run only for our files (or) is it possible to run based on function name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two main ways to control the coverage reports that are generated:

1. Telling your generator (e.g. `lcov`, `gcovr`) to include/exclude certain file patterns
2. Compiling only your source files with coverage enabled.

(1) is much easier than (2). For example, if you are using `lcov`, consider the [`--extract`](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php) option:

> Use  this switch if you want to extract coverage data for only a
>                 particular set of files from  a  tracefile.  Additional  command
>                 line  parameters  will be interpreted as shell wildcard patterns
>                 (note that they may need to be escaped  accordingly  to  prevent
>                 the  shell  from  expanding  them  first).   Every file entry in
>                 tracefile which matches at least one of those patterns  will  be
>                 extracted.

(2) could be difficult (or impossible) depending on your build system. To do so, you will need to:

1. Compile *only* your module with `--coverage` (equivalent to `-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs` for GNU compilers)
2. Link your library with `lgcov`.

This will produce the `*.gcno` 'notes' files that tell coverage generators about your source files *only* for the files that you compiled with the `--coverage` flags. Then, upon running your test suite, `*.gcda` files should only be generated for that same set of files. Running the final coverage report/HTML generator will only produce a report for your module.

To illustrate, here's a simple CMake file that only generates coverage information for `covered.cxx`. Notice the extra `target_compile_options` and `target_link_libraries` for the `covered` library.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cxx)                  

add_library(not-covered SHARED not-covered.cxx)           
add_library(covered SHARED covered.cxx)                   

target_compile_options(covered PRIVATE --coverage)        
target_link_libraries(covered PRIVATE --coverage)         

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} covered not-covered)
```